# Show that $\int_x^1\frac{dt}{1+t^2}=\int_1^{1/x}\frac{dt}{1+t^2},\;x>0.$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Show that $$\int_x^1\frac{dt}{1+t^2}=\int_1^{1/x}\frac{dt}{1+t^2},\;x>0.$$

So, I'm learning about integration techniques, and I get this exercise. We've been practicing $u$-substitution, and I think that might be involved here somehow, but I don't understand what I need to do to proceed. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your bounds on the second integral are in the wrong order: the integral on the left is positive and that on the right is negative.

Comment: Why was this question down-voted?

Comment: @MichaelHardy I was confused about that. I've transcribed the problem (Apostol's _Calculus_, 5.8.23) correctly, so the book must be erroneous. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
u & = \frac 1 t \\[8pt]
du & = \frac{-dt}{t^2} \\[8pt]
-t^2\,du & = dt \\[8pt]
\frac{-du}{u^2} & = dt
\end{align}
$$
When $t=x$ the $u=1/x$.

So
$$
\int_1^x \frac{dt}{1+t^2} = \int_1^{1/x} \frac{-du/u^2}{1+(1/u)^2} = \int_1^{1/x} \frac{-du}{u^2+1}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

the substitution $t \leftarrow 1/t$ yields
$$\int_1^x {dt\over 1 + t^2 } = \int_{1/x}^1 {dt/t^2\over 1 + (1/t)^2}
= \int_{1/x}^1 {dt\over 1 + t^2}. $$